# How to add a photo from user's album to an app/tab?

Tags: php, facebook

I can see how to access albums through the graph api but I am hoping there is a standard facebook dialog for selecting a photo from an album?

I have looked through the documentation and can't see it myself. I'm hoping I've just missed it somewhere.

Comment: what do you mean by this? `standard facebook dialog`

Comment: I think he means a Facebook UI element like the [request dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) or something that can be generated with XFBML or FB.ui js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook don't have 'standard dialog' but you can use few of the jQuery galleries and call the graph API. Here is a great starting point with some good code in it: http://code.google.com/p/facebook-photo-gallery/
Good luck.